# My discord bot works with different prefixes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

That's weird, but for some reason my bot works with different prefixes. I mean, at the very beggining for the code I set my prefix as "-". But the bot's commands also execute when typing "_, >, ? etc." Note that I'm using a command handler in my code so that could be an issue. Here's the full code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection } = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';
const PREFIX = '-';

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Compass is online');
    client.user.setActivity('GameCore', {type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.error);
})

client.on('message', message=>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'help':
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
            break;
        case 'kick':
            client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

If you need any other information feel free to tell me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;` to the start of your message event.

Comment: That is not what the OP is looking for. Please re-read the question and edit your answer acordingly.

Comment: As Jakye said, that's not what I'm looking for. Adding this into my code just makes my bot crash. I know this works, but I already have it set up in the top of the code, where I have `const prefix = '-'`. Then, I define what my args are supposed to be like in my `let` function. So, that's not helpful. I don't get the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Jakye was talking about my previous message. This piece of code works fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciated!